# how to select a specific html tag element and its content using simple perl script

Tags: html, regex, perl

## Input

Some content around this element **<span class="t39">abcd</span>** Some content around this element
 
Hello world **<span class="t39">efgh</span>** Some content around this element
Some content around this element **<span class="t39">ijk</span>** Some content around this element

## Output:

Some content around this element **<span class="t39">&#945;&#946;&#947;&#948;</span>** Some content around this element
 
Hello world **<span class="t39">&#949;&#966;&#978;&#951;</span>** Some content around this element
Some content around this element **<span class="t39">&#953;&#962;&#954;&#955;</span>** Some content around this element

**Entity conversion needed only** for the content inside the html element

I'm a beginner for the perl programming. kindly guide on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML), which can handle html as well.

```
open :F html 1.html ;
for //span[@class="t39"] {
    my $t = text();
    $t = { join q(), map chr(848 + ord), split //, $t } ;
    set . $t ;
}
save :b ;
```

Output is a bit different: it uses hexadecimal codes of the entities:

```html
<html>
<body>Some content around this element <span class="t39">&#x3B1;&#x3B2;&#x3B3;&#x3B4;</span> Some content around this element

Hello world <span class="t39">&#x3B5;&#x3B6;&#x3B7;&#x3B8;</span> Some content around this element

Some content around this element <span class="t39">&#x3B9;&#x3BA;&#x3BB;</span> Some content around this element
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can maybe say, that you want to encode things between '>' and '<' (closing and opening HTML brackets - or whatever they are called :) ). In that case you can use a regex, like this:

```
sub do_something {
    my $string = shift;
    return $string." perl is awesome";
}
my $text = "some text <span blabla>my text</span>other text";
$text =~ s/>(.*)</">".do_something($1)."<"/e
```

With the =~, you can 'apply' a regex to a variable. I'm using here the form s/search_this/replace_it_for_this/e . s/ means substitute. >(.*)< means find anything between the characters '>' and '<'. (more on this: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

the /e switch lets you execute perl functions in the regex. In the 'replace_for_this' part of the regex we have ">".do_something($1)."<" .It will replace the string we found with the character > followed by the return value of the do_something function followed by the character <. The $1 in the argument of the do_something function is the string we found in the 'search_this' part of the regex (which got saved into $1 thanks to the parenteses.

For the actual encoding..Do you need to encode all the characters, or just some special ones? In the latter case I'd encourage you to have a look at this module: [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aEntities) . It does just that.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said, using perl library is better because regex are very bad to parse balanced text

useful libraries

HTML::Parser complete, but not easy for beginner.

HTML::TokeParser::Simple is very simple for beginner

You can also use code below, if you like some funny regex

```
my (@res) = grep { !/span/i  } $str =~ m/<(span)[^>]*> #memorize span and find attributes 
                                          (.+?)       #minimum search
                                         <\/\1>       #\1 is for span memorized
                                         /gmixs;
```

grep delete first memorized search => span

The whole search result is pulled in array.

THIS CANNOT be used if your tags are nested. Regex doesn't work.

Sample:
<div><div>texte</div></div>